# operador <= no lo reconoce java en una sentencia sql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Tengo una sentencia SQL, en java para realizar un delete luego de que una variable ya tenga mas de 3 días, y cuando ejecuto la sentencia me genera error, cuando uso el operador `>=` funciona perfecto,
al igual que cuando le tenía solo el

```
<delete id="truncateItinerario">
   TRUNCATE itinerarios
</delete>
```

esta es la sentencia

```
<delete id="truncateItinerario">
    DELETE FROM itinerarios WHERE fecciudhasta <= (NOW() - INTERVAL '6 hours');
</delete>
```

y este es el error que se me genera

> Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 49; El contenido de los elementos debe constar de marcadores o datos de carácter con un formato correcto.
>       at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)

Comment: el archivo del cual el java lee, la sentencia sql es un .xml

Comment: Puedes adjuntar el XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola @VíctorEduardoDuqueRosales, el problema que tienes es porque `Mayor que` y `Menor que` son parte de la especificación de XML, porque son la apertura y el cierre de un `TAG` y al procesa el archivo XML este termina en un error de estructura por el Parse `SAXParseException`.

Para solucionar esto tienes 2 opciones

1.Convertir los `< >` en sus equivalentes xml `&lt; y &gt;`

```
<delete id="truncateItinerario">
  DELETE FROM itinerarios WHERE fecciudhasta &lt;= (NOW() - INTERVAL '6 hours');
</delete>
```

2.Usar CDATA para espesificar que lo que esta dentro no debe ser analizado por el Parse:

```
<delete id="truncateItinerario">
    DELETE FROM itinerarios WHERE fecciudhasta  <![CDATA[ <=  (NOW() - INTERVAL '6 hours'); ]]>
</delete>
```

Esto técnicamente no es un error de ibatis, sino de XML `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException`

Comment: Muchas gracias , he usado la primera opcion.

Comment: Que bueno que te funciono, lo bueno es tener en mente cual de las 2 opciones por si tienes muchas conversiones metes todo en el CDATA.

Comment: exactamente, esta vez me funciona la primera opción, por ser una validación simple, pero en un caso un poco mas complejo, es mas prolijo la segunda, y así se evita cualquier error futuro al copiar y pegar sentencias directo del pgadmin jjejej